# The headmaster said "why?" change it into indirect speech

Tags: grammar, reported-speech

I'm facing trouble changing it. Would you please help me solve the problem?

> The headmaster said "why?"

Change the above sentence into indirect speech please.

Comment: Hello, Zafor. Could you explain why you think << The headmaster said "Why?" >> (note the capitalisation) is a suitable string for conversion into 'indirect speech'? It's an odd sentence to start with; 'say' isn't a normal quotative verb for questions, drawing attention to the actual uttering when chosen. is he offering a possible solution to a crossword clue? //  Unless there are arbitrary rules of conversion in play here, I'd use _The headmaster asked why._ informally and _The headmaster asked us why we had_ .... (etc) in a formal register.

Comment: Actually i have taken it from a passage where it was written as - the student said, "We want to celebrate the victory of the national debate competition." The headmaster said, "Why?" then what would be the right answer - the headmaster asked why.is it?

Comment: Apologies for the embarrassing typo;  sentence-initial 'is' should be 'Is', of course. // I've looked at the [original {as far as I can see} exercise](https://www.facebook.com/577558162714564/posts/narrationspeech-previous-board-test-exam-questions-for-ssc1change-the-narrative-/1080626149074427/) and would not be happy if my grandchildren were using material of such a standard to try to learn (British) English.

Answer (score 1):

- The headmaster said, “Why?”

could be changed into

- The headmaster **asked** why.

Comment: To improve the answer, you should add some explanation of _why_ this is the appropriate indirect speech version.